# Why i get null or undefined value for this code, i am trying to connect my botpress with stackAi,

Tags: artificial-intelligence, botpress, knowledge-base-population

Here is the code

```
const endpoint = "https://www.stack-inference.com/run_deployed_flow?flow_id=64b1aa0eeb1096a9b84e20ef&org=e55254da-2736-41bb-9549-798937b4a981";

const headers = {
  Authorization: 'Bearer 769ecdad-dd21-48fe-988b-78e188440e34',
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
};

const data = {
  
  "in-0": workflow.questionaskedbyuser
};

try {

    const response = await axios.post(endpoint, data, { headers });
    workflow.ApiResponse = response.data["out-0"];
  
} catch (error) {
  throw new Error(`stack-error: ${error}`);
}
```

I deployed stackai onto botpress, i was expecting an output from stackai so that i can use it in my botpress, but it's not sending me the output, either it's null or undefined.